How to properly set up radio buttons on pdf exported from jasper reports? Can uuid from elements be generated from data?
I'm creating a report which is a pdf with form inputs.
I use jasper reports library version 6.20.0
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
  <version>6.20.0</version>
</dependency>

I'm making use of the net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.* properties to set them up.
Inside a detail band I set up a subreport with a datasource made from a collection of beans. In a subreport band I configure the textInput element for a radio button and textInput for a label.

The first textInput is configured with pdf export properties:
(Not in the XML syntax)
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.type    Radio
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.name    $F{radioGrupo}
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.checked false

My intent is to show dynamically any number of lists of radio buttons in the main report. I intend to work them properly but when I click one of them all become checked:

EDIT: Has the uuid on the XML element something to do with It? When rendering the PDF in firefox, chrome and edge browsers the radio gets the proper behaviour but no in Acrobat reader.
EDIT: I provide a sample pdf with the problem: prueba_radio.pdf
EDIT: Answering @KJ (thank you very much for your atention). I see what is happending: internally that id is being held for me. It comes from the uuid created by jaspersoft studio. That element being repeated in the export at filling time gets the same value. Can uuid from elements be generated from data (parameter, variable or field)? 
When i define net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.name this gets the browser navigators to work correctly but it's not affecting acrobat reader.

The properties were only listed for reference not syntaxed @KJ
